# Hide steps in logs in Github Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to hide a step from a github actions workflow in the logs in a way, that it is being executed in the background but not displayed?

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set Environment Variables
        run: |
          echo "Setting environment variables"
          echo "::add-mask::${{ env.PASSWORD }}"
        env:
          PASSWORD: ${{ github.event.inputs.password }}
      - name: Run Script
```

I've tried it already like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set Environment Variables
        run: |
          echo "Setting environment variables"
          echo "::add-mask::${{ env.PASSWORD }}"
        env:
          PASSWORD: ${{ github.event.inputs.password }}
        background: true
        silent: true
      - name: Run Script
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide some steps? What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: `background` and `silent` are not valid configuration options. See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why and what you want to achieve exactly, I'll just cover a few points that you might be missing:

### Environment variables can be set globally, on job and step levels

What you are trying to do here:

```
  - name: Set Environment Variables
    run: |
      echo "Setting environment variables"
      echo "::add-mask::${{ env.PASSWORD }}"
    env:
      PASSWORD: ${{ github.event.inputs.password }}
```

Does not add any value, your `PASSWORD` variable is scoped only to that step.

If you want to set this environment variable just define a [`env:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow) block for:

> - The entire workflow, by using `env` at the top level of the workflow file.
> - The contents of a job within a workflow, by using [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv).
> - A specific step within a job, by using [`jobs.<job_id>.steps\[*\].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv).

### Secrets won't be shown on the console

Secrets won't be shown on the console even if you try to log them with `echo` and `cat`. GitHub is doing a good job of hiding these secrets from being accidentally logged, they get replaced in the outputs with `***`

---

Now if you want to hide some noise (repetitive setup/preparation steps):

### Run your "hidden" stuff from a script

You can create a bash script for example then run it from your pipelines, the script will perform the necessary steps you don't want to expose as steps in GitHub Actions, for example:

```
  - name: Do Something
    working-directory: somepath
    shell: bash
    run: |
      ./path/to/script/my-script.sh
```

Or, just run a multiline script in your action without using an external script file.

```
  - name: Do Something
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "do something"
      # ..
      # ...
      SOMETHING=$(...)
```

### Use a Docker image to run your workflow

For example, if you need to perform some setup and prepare something before you run the steps you want to see in the workflow run...

Just prepare a Docker image in which you'll spin and run your actions inside.

```
jobs:
  container-test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: my-docker-artifactory.url.domain/path/to/image:tag
    steps:
      - name: Do Something
        run: ...
```

See [Running jobs in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container).